# Cannot copy file, after converting to exe file shutil python

Tags: python, windows, pyinstaller, shutil

I've been trying to copy python script, that I use to startup folder. Everything works as it should, BUT after I compile the script into .exe file, I always get this error:

```
File "shutil.py", line 417, in copy
  File "shutil.py", line 254, in copyfile
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\x\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\_MEI187322\\script.exe'
```

This is the code:

```
pathFile = os.path.join("C:\\", "Users", os.getlogin(), "AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup", "script.exe")

pathCurrent = os.path.realpath(__file__)

if pathCurrent != pathFile:
    try:
        shutil.copy(pathCurrent, pathFile)
    except shutil.SameFileError:
        pass

else:
    pass
```

Comment: `_MEI187322` is the temporary directory where your `pyinstaller` executable unpacks everything needed to run your program, and it is the program's current working directory. So when your program goes looking for `script.exe`, that is where it looks. But for it to be there, you have to tell `pyinstaller` to put it there (in the `.spec` file). And if you don't know what a `.spec` file is, it's time to read the `pyinstaller` documentation.

Comment: script.exe is the same thing as this python script. I just want it to copy itself from current path to startup folder. If I understand you correctly, you think that I meant to copy another program with my script. Or did I misunderstand?

Comment: All I am saying is you are getting *file not found* in that folder because the file isn't there. If `script.exe` is the file `pyinstaller` is creating (your question didn't explain that) you need another approach. You can't tell `pyinstaller` to include its output  (the self-extracting zipfile it is creating) inside that output.

Comment: :( that's exactly what I was trying to do

Comment: if I compile it and then add that exe to pyinstaller --add-data "blabla path" would it work?

Comment: i guess it doesn't. Maybe if I try to configure it somehow....

Comment: Probably not. At best you would get the *previous* version of the file. And it would make the executable twice as big. At this point I think you need to ask yourself why it is necessary for your executable to make a copy of itself and if there is a different way to achieve whatever it was you were aiming at.